# Call to a member function take() on array laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.2 and what I want to do is to populate a jQuery Datatable from information from my database. Here is my code to do that:

```
Route::get('/a/VentasPorSucursal', function(){
   $values = [1, 8000, 2, "NULL", "2018-06-10", "2018-08-10", "NULL", "NULL"];
   $data = DB::select('SP_RPT_VENTAS2 ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?', $values)->take(10);

   return Datatables::of(collect($data))->make(true);
});
```

When I run my app I get the following error message:

> Call to a member function take() on array

If I remove this part of my code everything works fine:

```
->take(10)
```

I also tried using **->paginate(10)** but I get the same error message.

What could be the problem?

Comment: `DB::select(...)` returns an Array, and `take()` is not a valid method of an array. Maybe add a `LIMIT 10` (or db equivalent) to your statement?

Comment: @TimLewis Ok, I understand that, but after adding a limit x to my statement I'm going to do another function to display the next 10 rows right?

Comment: Then wouldn't you do an `OFFSET 10`? That being said though, I don't know what `SP_RPT_VENTAS2` is or what it does... To me it just looks like you're selecting static values and expecting there to be 10+ rows.

Comment: @TimLewis It's a stored procedure (from sql server) that gets all the info between the two static dates in $values array

Comment: I guessed it was something like that. I'm sure there's a way to convert a Sproc to a `Builder` instance, which would let you use `->paginate()`, amongst other builder methods, but unfortunately I don't know it.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use `->take(10)->get();` insted of only `->take(10);`